# Only owner can enable Bluetooth on CyanogenMod

Tags: cyanogenmod, bluetooth, multi-user

I'm using an LG GPad 8.3 (v500) with CyanogenMod 12.1-20151007 and on this device only the "owner" is able to activate Bluetooth. There was a [similar bug in CyanogenMod 10.1](https://jira.cyanogenmod.org/browse/CYAN-1502).

Is there a workaround to allow other users than the own to use Bluetooth? It would be ok, to create another "owner", but this seems to be impossible.

Comment: Have you tried  other CM based ROMs ?

Comment: @rajatpunkstaa Not yet. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I'll say because CM based ROMs have Cyanogenmod as the base plus extra features in them. So you might wanna check them out. It will have all the base CM features. 
One good option to go with is [Paranoid Android](http://www.paranoidandroid.co/). 
Some other ROMs : [Bliss Pop](http://blissroms.com/) , [Resurrection Remix](http://www.resurrectionremix.com/).
 
Try them and tell me what you find ! 
Good Luck !

Comment: @deamon Sorry couldn't provide you with links coz I'm out of city right now !   Try google and i hope you find them.